# Unicode error PHP

Tags: php, url, unicode, href

I have Wordpress website and on the 1 page I use theme from file.
Code is right, but the src or href are bad.
Example:

```
$url = site_url()."/blog/".get_the_ID();
```

It's shows:

```
http://localhost/blog/144%E2%80%8E/
```

In the debugger of Firefox links are right:

```
http://localhost/blog/144/
```

If anybody can help, please write!!

Comment: What is `get_the_ID()` doing? There is a U+200E character in the returned value (which is Left-To-Right Mark, a bidi control character you definitely don't want to allow in URLs). When this is formatted as a Unicode IRI that's shown as an actual control character rather than the `%xx` sequence but either way it's bad and you should probably be filtering out non-digit IDs.

Answer (score 0):

[urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) will be the simplest solution here. You can pass the incoming string and use the return value to set `$url`. As an aside, it seems you have an extra character coming through the url following the 144.

Comment: It's not works, because the unicode is added not in code. Maybe you have any other idea ?